# Is this bird a woodpecker?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

This bugger is pecking on the side of my house. I don’t know anything about birds, but it doesn’t look like your typical woodpecker.

[image: Bird]

Comment: BTW, the pecking may be due to finding a plentiful supply of insects in your siding.

Answer (score 7):

That is a red breasted nuthatch.(https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Red-breasted_Nuthatch/id

Include a location next time,it helps with identification.

Comment: See how the top part of the beak is flatter than the bottom part of the beak. That helps them catch the insects that they eat.